# What could be causing rippling and staining in a hardwood floor?

Tags: flooring

Since the start 11 years ago there has been a problem with staining and rippling in our kitchens flooring. Just one area. It was repaired three times early on and lasted about seven years, then just before our ten years was up the builder had us replace it again. It has been tested for water and gas leaks to no avail. The last repair lasted only about 10 months. I want new flooring but can't proceed without discovering the culprit. Do you think I need to hire an engineer to come and diagnose the problem?

Comment: You could measure the humidity level of the floor periodically which may help you narrow down your search

Comment: Any chance you can post a pic of the area in question? I suspect moisture is the issue from what details you've written but a picture or 2 would give me a better idea.

Comment: Your only question seems to be whether you need to hire an engineer, which isn't really up to us. I'd be able to figure it out, and so can you, if you want to. Instead, revise your post to ask for help doing so and provide photos.

Comment: What is under the hardwoods, are you on a slab or basement?